# Всегда ли есть смысл использовать асинхронные версии методов?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, async-await, асинхронность

Причины для использования асинхронности о которых читал:

- не держать поток для ожидания ответа из внешних источников (IO), полезно и для бека и для UI приложений
- дать отзывчивость для UI если есть долгая операция вычисления с использованием `await Task.Run(...);` (CPU задачи)

Если имеем дело только с ASP.NET Core, то как я понял вторая причина не актуальна и многие асинхронные методы кажутся не нужными.
Многих примеров не знаю, но думаю иногда нет смысла предпочитать `Stream.ReadAsync` и `Stream.CopyToAsync` если используем для преобразования данных в локальной памяти. Или вот еще примеры кода без особого контекста, которые быстро нагуглил:

```
var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(urisource);
await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); // это должно происходить уже после получения ответа из внешних источников, поэтому не вижу смысла в асинхронности для ASP.NET Core
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

и

```
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
var byteArray = buffer.ToArray();
var responseString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
```

Уверен что можно вспомнить или найти еще много примеров. Возможно такое пишут именно для UI, но возможно я что-то упускаю. Всегда ли есть смысл использовать асинхронные версии операций?

Comment: `вторая причина не актуальна и многие асинхронные методы кажутся не нужными` - а теперь предположим, что ваш сайт посетило разом 1000 человек, где каждый ждет от сервера выполнения некой задачи, а тот ждет, к примеру, пока ответит база для выполнения задачи первого клиента, из-за чего запрос висит в ожидании, у клиента долгая страница загрузки, а за ним еще 999 человек в очереди. Чего не обслужить другого клиента, пока ожидается база? Вот вам и `дать отзывчивость для UI`.

Comment: Эта проблема закрыта первой причиной использования асинхронных методов о которой я писал.

Answer (score 2):

Если метод объявлен как возвращающий задачу - это означает одно из двух:

1. Этот метод где-то внутри делает операцию ввода-вывода;
2. Сигнатура этого метода задаётся более общей абстракцией, а самому методу асинхронность не нужна;
3. Асинхронность была добавлена "для галочки".

Так вот, если отбросить второй и третий варианты - то все оставшиеся асинхронные методы таки делают ввод-вывод, а потому лучше использовать именно их чем их синхронные версии (если последние вообще есть).

Например, указанный вами метод `HttpContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync` асинхронен не просто так, а потому что он реально дочитывает ответ HTTP до конца, если метод `GetAsync` был вызван с опцией `HttpCompletionOptions.ResponseHeadersRead`

Впрочем, иногда вы таки можете гарантировать что ожидания не будет, к примеру после вызова `HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsync` последующие чтения из буфера уже не будут выполнять ввод-вывод.

Примером второго случая, когда также не обязательно использовать асинхронные методы, является чтение и запись в MemoryStream: он "наследует" асинхронность из Stream, но сам никогда не выполняет ввода-вывода. Но вот его метод CopyToAsync всё ещё может ожидать при копировании в обычный поток.

В общем, иногда отказ от асинхронности допустим, но в общем случае лучше использовать асинхронные методы, особенно если вы не вполне понимаете то что они делают.

Comment: _GetAsync читает лишь заголовки_ - не совсем так. Чтобы он читал только заголовки, надо явно указывать `HttpCompletionOptions.ResponseHeadersRead`. Почти всегда почти никто, конечно же не указывает, как результат `HttpContent.ReadAs***Async()` завершается синхронно, потому что данные уже в буфере. Во всяком случае, это справедливо для небольших HTTP пакетов.

Comment: @aepot хм, и правда

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете, что какая-то операция выполняется заведомо быстро и затраты на создание `state machine` просто не окупятся, то можете не использовать асинхронность. Но стоит ли такая экономия (если она вообще будет) того, чтобы нарушать универсальность подхода, вводить какие-то исключения? Универсальный подход всё же в том, чтобы использовать асинхронность везде, где она доступна. Обычно это всё же хорошо: программа освобождает поток от бесполезного простаивания в том месте кода, где есть вероятность, что поток будет просто ждать окончания какой-то операции ввода-вывода. Если программа хорошо написана, то освобождённый поток сможет заняться чем-то полезным, сделать какую-то другую работу, которую пришла пора сделать. И в результате программа будет более быстрой и более отзывчивой.

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае асинхронность позволяет более рационально использовать ресурсы.

Если разобрать это на вашем примере с вычитыванием массива байт, то представьте что у вас есть метод в контроллере в котором надо вычитывать огромный массив и вычитывание занимает условно 1 минуту.

Асинхронная реализация как раз позволит более грамотно распределить ресурсы и не займёт поток на целую минуту пока он ждёт результат.
В это время освобождённый поток может обрабатывать другие запросы и ваш сервер будут более отзывчивым.

В случае с синхронной реализацией метода велика вероятность того, что при большом количестве пользователей, которые используют этот метод, при очередном вызове этого метода вызывающий код просто станет в очередь за свободным потоком.

Поэтому в общем случае рекомендуется использовать именно асинхронные методы. Если только нет каких-то явных причин, поэтому этого делать не стоит (например, сам по себе асинхронный метод в общем случае будет выполняться чуть дольше чем синхронный).